# Classic ASP Upload Throws Error

Tags: asp-classic

Good evening

I have been playing around with File upload i wanted to upload a File and have it send to the server and i Wanted to do this in plain Classic ASP

Saw some codes online and Played with it, Except it gave some Errors with IIS. Code looks like this

```
<HTML>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
   <FORM METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="UploadScript1.asp">
      <INPUT TYPE="FILE" SIZE="40" NAME="FILE1"><BR>
      <INPUT TYPE="FILE" SIZE="40" NAME="FILE2"><BR>
      <INPUT TYPE="FILE" SIZE="40" NAME="FILE3"><BR>
   <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Upload!">
   </FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and the back end script looks like this

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Count = Upload.Save("c:\upload")
Response.Write Count & " file(s) uploaded to c:\upload"
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

After enabling the debugger i got something that looks like this

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/uploadtest/UploadScript1.asp, line 4

800401f3
```

What could be Wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The object Persits.Upload is a third-party component (a COM object) that has to be installed on the server. You can download a trial and/or purchase it here: http://www.aspupload.com/manual.html

Comment: Um, good sir, Other than Object Persists , How about using python in ASP or javascript to do a file upload to the server? What do you think? good Idea ?

Comment: I'm actually very familiar with Persits' ASPUpload and to be honest, I think it's the easiest way to just make it work in Classic ASP. I'd fork over the $200 for a single user license if I could. In particular, it will handle large uploads better.

Comment: If you're looking for something free, or you don't have the option of installing a third party component on the server I recommend FreeAspUpload.  The website has disappeared, but you can find it on the internet archive here - https://web.archive.org/web/20121014153715/http://freeaspupload.net/